# Setting up a if attribute

Tags: php

For Example > if content = tree return special content to tree

content being > index.php?content=tree

```
<?php
if (<?= $_GET['content'] ?> == tree) {
echo "text here";
}
else {
echo "nothing to see here";
}
?>
```

Comment: remove this tags: `<?=` and `?>` also put `tree` in quotes like `"tree"`

Comment: Is it JavaScript or PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First i advice you check functions and other php code on the php manual, Heres an example of the if/elseif/else statement: [link](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)

Now in your code you did this:     `if (<?= $_GET['content'] ?> == tree) {`

Note how you called php echo     `<?= $_GET['content'] ?> == tree` as a condition, first mistake there since you cant call php as a condition, not to mention echo.
this is how you should have wrote the code:

```
<?php

    if ($_GET['content'] == 'tree') { 

        echo "text here";

    }
    else {

        echo "nothing to see here";

    }

?>
```

Please check out the link i gave you.

Answer (score 2):

Fixed up:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['content']) && $_GET['content'] == 'tree') {
echo "text here";
}
else {
echo "nothing to see here";
}
?>
```

Multiple:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['content']) && in_array($_GET['content'], array('tree', 'bird', 'fish', 'taco')) ) {
echo "text here";
}
else {
echo "nothing to see here";
}
?>
```

Comment: should be wise to include `isset($_GET['content'])`. Otherwise it will throw warnings

Comment: isset($_GET['content']) && $_GET['content'] == 'tree' tho :)

Comment: can i use `if ($_GET['content'] == 'tree','pollom','seeka') {` ?

Comment: @Daniel think your looking for the `||` OR operator :D

Comment: If you separate them then yeah! @Daniel. Exactly how Rizer said to do it.

Comment: or [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

Comment: If you want to use an array use this **if (in_array($_GET['content'], array(1, 3, 4, 5)) ) {** Il also update my answer.